# Tools to design code for dynamic web interface

Tags: java, netbeans, embeddedwebserver

I am looking for an easy way to design a simple web interface for a java application to control some settings from another computer.
I have looked at a few possibilites like embedding a [Jetty](https://wiki.eclipse.org/Jetty/Tutorial/Embedding_Jetty) or [Tomcat](http://www.copperykeenclaws.com/embedding-tomcat-7/) server. Altho i guess Jetty will be better choice for a simple web interface to control a few settings of an application.
It might even be enough to use build in [HTTPServer](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/jre/api/net/httpserver/spec/com/sun/net/httpserver/HttpServer.html).

But all the tutorials so far show simple Hello World examples. It would be easy to follow those and build all the pages i want to show with simple string builder, but that is quite tedious work.

It is possible to pass JSPs to the embedded servers, but so far i haven't found a good designer for those either. It seems there are a few vidual designers availiable for Eclipse, but i am working with NetBeans and don't want to switch just for this. It seems NetBeans hat a visual desinger in Version 6, but it was removed again. There is [vaadin](https://vaadin.com/tooling), but NetBeans Plugin Central seems to be down at the moment, so i can't check it out.

Are there any other tools availiable to design simple web interfaces? Preferably usable with NetBeans, but if it needs some work to integrate the finished page i can live with it.

Answer (score 0):

In most cases people use web technologies "code centric". So most tools focus on getting the maximum out of the source code (HTML, CSS, javascript, java libraries).

That being said, you might want to take a look at Wavemaker (http://www.wavemaker.com/) or OpenXava (http://www.openxava.org/) which ease the development of a simple web application.